# double reminder operation in python

Tags: python, double

In the below Python code taken from a library, why is the program checking for coefficient `%1 ==0`? What is the purpose of that line and why we are converting to `int` type for coefficient?

```
def write_coefficient(coefficient, is_initial_term=False):
            coefficient = round(coefficient, num_decimal_places)
            if coefficient % 1 == 0:
                coefficient = int(coefficient)

            output = ''

            if coefficient < 0:
                output += '-'
            if coefficient > 0 and not is_initial_term:
                output += '+'

            if not is_initial_term:
                output += ' '

            if abs(coefficient) != 1:
                output += '{}'.format(abs(coefficient))

            return output
```

Comment: The purpose is to test if the number is an integer without rounding or coercing. 

Can't say why converting it is the best option though.

Comment: One unrelated possible bug: the coefficient is rounded to `num_decimal_places`, but the `format` call doesn't use `num_decimal_places` to actually show exactly that many decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Round there gives you an answer to num_decimal_places. The % checks if it is a whole number i.e .0000, then if it is, convert it to an int cause the .000 is unnecessary.

Comment: I wonder if this answer gives much insight. Consider to give some examples to 'show' what the floor division operator exactly does.